# How do I set a button to delete its parent element in the button's constructor?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating a code behind that creates a scrollable list of informational frames based on data from an API I set up. Each frame has a background color to indicate a status I'm monitoring as well as a button to open up an informational dialogue and a button to remove the frame from the list. This is the code I have right now:

```cs
Frame alert_frame = new Frame
                    {
                        BorderColor = Color.Black,
                        BackgroundColor = color,
                        StyleId = obj.EventKey,
                        Content = new StackLayout
                        {
                            Orientation = Xamarin.Forms.StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                            Padding = 0,
                            Margin = 0,
                            Children =
                            {
                                new Button
                                {
                                    BackgroundColor=color,
                                    VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                                    HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                                    TextColor=Color.White,
                                    FontSize=30,
                                    FontAttributes=FontAttributes.Bold,
                                    Text="Info",
                                    Command=(System.Windows.Input.ICommand)DisplayAlert("Event Info",obj.Change,"Okay")
                                },
                                new Button
                                {
                                    BackgroundColor=color,
                                    VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                                    HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                                    TextColor=Color.White,
                                    FontSize=30,
                                    FontAttributes=FontAttributes.Bold,
                                    Text="Delete",
                                    Command= //This is what I need help with
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    };
```

I have a function called Remove that returns the desired parent frame and that function works correctly, so the problem I'm facing now is figuring out how I can cast the command

```cs
alert_stack.Children.Remove(Remove(obj))
```

Into the proper type to be set to the command attribute. The most recent thing I tried was

```cs
new Command(() => alert_stack.Children.Remove(Remove(obj)))
```

But this returned an invalid cast error upon running it. Does anyone have any idea how this might be done? Would it be better to create a separate function to create the buttons and their OnClick attributes and return them as a list and have that set to the children attribute of the StackLayout?

I appreciate any help

Comment: Let's say you've got a list of items from API, and you intend to remove one by clicking the "del" button. Is there a ListView or CollectionView to display on the page, do you mean to remove the item in the list or just remove the UI frame and keep the same list?

Comment: @Falcon007 I can not understand this code `alert_stack.Children.Remove(Remove(obj))`, why there are two remove? For example, you want to click Button to remove current frame, it is also Button's parent?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT The second remove is a poorly titled function I created that simply returns the parent frame, which is the child of alert_stack I'm trying to remove

Comment: @Shaw I have a ScrollView in the xaml with a StackLayout as the child. The code behind references this StackLayout (named alert_stack) and adds frames to it according to the data received from the API. Each frame has two buttons. I want to remove the frame from the StackLayout when the del button is clicked but not change anything else.

Comment: @Falcon007 I try this code, can delete current frame in stacklayout: `Button b = (Button)sender; Frame f = (Frame)btn1.Parent; stack1.Children.Remove(f);`